# For $A \in F_2^{N \times M}$ find $\mathbf x \in F_2^M$ to maximize $L_0$ norm of $A \mathbf x$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, finite-fields, combinatorial-geometry

I have an optimization problem: For  a fixed matrix  $A \in F_2^{M \times N}$ find a vector $\mathbf x \in F_2^{N \times 1}$ such that the vector $\mathbf y = A \mathbf x \in F_2^{M \times 1}$ has maximum Hamming weight/$L_0$ norm.

- Recall that the hamming weight/L0 norm of a vector $\mathbf y \in F_2^M$ is the number of 1-entries in the vector: $hamming(\mathbf y) \equiv |\{ i : \mathbf  y[i] = 1 \}|$.
- All the algebra occurs over $F_2$.

Compactly, we wish to solve for $\mathbf x^*$ given $A$:

$$
\mathbf x^\star \equiv \arg \max_{\mathbf x \in F_2^{N \times 1}} |\{ i: (A \mathbf x)[i] = 1 \}|
$$

I don't what problems of this type are called, and what their asymptotic complexity is. It seems to me that there is a tension between the linear-algebra that occurs over $F_2$ and the counting of 1-entries that occurs over $\mathbb Z$. I was hoping for references to:

- Algorithms to solve such a system of constraints if it is easy.
- Complexity theoretic results about the hardness of such problems if it is hard.

**Note** formally speaking, $L_0$ is number of *non-zero* entries. In our case, we have only $0/1$ entries. So, number of non-zero entries is the same as number of one-entries.

Comment: This is non-convex problem. I am bit confused why would you call it $L_1$-norm? Its more similar to $L_0$-norm. We may write it as $x^* := arg\max \|Ax - \mathds{1}\|_0$

Comment: You're right, I guess $L_0$ is closer in spirit. I wrote $L_1$ since it's the "sum of vector elements", which are only 0/1. Let me change this...

Comment: http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2013/09/4053.pdf Its mentioned in the Introduction minimizing $L_0$ norm subject to even linear constraints is NP-Hard

Comment: How do we know that the problem over $F_2$ is equivalent to the problem over $\mathbb R$? It's unclear to me that we can take results from LP and conclude the hardness of this problem. If you can fill that in as well, then I'll be happy to accept an answer.

Comment: Yeah. It seems difficult to prove for $F_2$.